# create custom carbon component

Tags: osgi, bundle, wso2

I read [this](http://wso2.com/premium/webinars/creating-your-own-wso2-carbon-components) and tried to create my own component. I got the student-manager sample, but I don't know how I can create the project from scratch? I also try to develop a osgi bundle using [this](http://sameera.adahas.org/2010/01/developing-osgi-bundles-for-wso2-carbon.html) and install this bundle into AS, and start/stop the bundle. My thought is that, how can I then write a method and expose it as web service? then generate the stub, and write the UI component? is there a doc about this? what about carbon-p2-plugin? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did the below answer solve your problem? If so, it would be great if you could mark this question as Answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: How to expose a web service?
Yes, the student-manager sample [1] has a sample web service implementation. This has been done using Axis2. What you need to do is to define a services.xml file at component/src/main/resources/META-INF/ folder and specify the service implementation class in it:

```
<serviceGroup>
      <service name="StudentManager" scope="transportsession">
        <transports>
            <transport>https</transport>
        </transports>
        <parameter name="ServiceClass">org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.StudentManager</parameter>
    </service>
    <parameter name="adminService" locked="true">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="hiddenService" locked="true">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="AuthorizationAction" locked="true">/permission/admin/protected</parameter>
</serviceGroup>
```

Q2: How to generate the client service stub?
Once you are ready with your web service, deploy the component in a Carbon server and start the server. Then access the WSDL and use WSDL2Java tool to generate the client service stub.

Q3: How to write a Carbon UI component?
Please refer articles [2] & [3] for implementing Carbon UI components.

Q4: What does P2-Plugin do?
Equinox-p2 has added provisioning (install/update/uninstall) features for OSGi bundles [4]. This is a value added feature for managing carbon features in a more user friendly manner.

[1] http://wso2.com/premium/webinars/creating-your-own-wso2-carbon-components

[2] http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/build-ui-component-wso2-carbon-platform-part-1

[3] http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Creating+Carbon+Projects#CreatingCarbonProjects-CarbonUIBundleProject

[4] http://wso2.com/projects/carbon/provisioning-wso2-carbon-with-equinox-p2/

Comment: Thanks Imesh. And I see Carbon 5 is on the way. mail list shows axis2 is going to be aborted? So what will be the base then?

Comment: AFAIK, Carbon 5 will not tightly depend on Axis2 (as in Carbon 4.x and earlier) and Axis2 will be continued to use as a runtime provider for Carbon.